# How can I convert 1D array into 2D matrix on MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, heatmap

I want to make heatmap with 1D array(s), this is my plan; 
Let assume 4 points of center and each has array, 
[center #1, L U] = {0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 7, 4, 2, 1, 0} *L R U D =  Left, Right, Up, Down
[center #2, R U] = {0, 1, 1, 4, 12, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1} 
[center #3, L D] = {0, 1, 3, 4, 11, 7, 4, 2, 1, 0} 
[center #4, R D] = {0, 1, 3, 6, 11, 6, 5, 3, 1, 1} 
And when 5th index of heatmap, ([#1]=10, [#2]=12, [#3]=11, [#4]=11) heatmap needs to be like this image. 
[Heatmap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dn3e.png) 
Also can predict heatmap is all blue when 1st index ([#1]=0, [#2]=0, [#3]=0, [#4]=0) 
 and only right side has color that almost blue when last index. ([#1]=0, [#2]=1, [#3]=0, [#4]=1)
How can I get 2D matrix from 1D arrays on Matlab? Decreasing values from center can be linear or whatever.

Comment: I don't understand any of what you are really trying to do. You have 4 10x1 arrays. Ok, and how should you resulting matrix look like?

Comment: @Bernhard I want to make arrays into heatmap video, with example metioned above, first frame of this video is 4 NxN zero matrices, second frame of video is 4 NxN matrices that center has value 1. Surroundings values of 1 are decreasing uniformly..

Comment: Still not very clear. Could you perhaps add a example to your question of what the 2D matrix (or at least part of it) would look like.

Comment: Could you add a [mcve] ?

Comment: If N=5, [Example](http://i.imgur.com/hXUC9qj.png) , at last, attach these 4 matrices in each frames into one 10x10 matrix per frames

Comment: [Result](http://i.imgur.com/IaNEI4F.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example you wish to produce always 4 n * n matrices, where the center point of each matrix gets the value in your arrays and all its 4-neighbors get a decreasing value until zero. Did I get it right?

Does this create one of the four matrices you wished to create? If so, just modify the parameters and make four matrices and draw them together

```
% your matrix size
size = 15

center =  (size + 1) / 2

center_value = 5

mat_a = zeros(size,size);
mat_a(center,center) = center_value;
%loop all values until zero
for ii=1:center_value -1
  current_value = center_value - ii;
  update_mat = mat_a;
  % loop over matrix, check if 4-neighbors non-zero
  for x =1:size
    for y =1:size
      if ( mat_a(y,x) == 0 )
        has_non_zero_neighbor = false;
        % case 1 
        if ( x < size) 
          if (mat_a(y,x+1) > 0)
             has_non_zero_neighbor = true; 
           endif
         endif
         % case 2
         if ( y < size) 
           if (mat_a(y+1,x) > 0)
             has_non_zero_neighbor = true; 
           endif
         endif
         %case 3
         if ( x > 1)
          if (mat_a(y,x-1) > 0)
             has_non_zero_neighbor = true; 
           endif
         endif
         % case 4
         if ( y > 1) 
          if (mat_a(y-1,x) > 0)
             has_non_zero_neighbor = true; 
           endif
         endif  

         %if non-zeros, update matrix item value to current value
         if (has_non_zero_neighbor == true)    
           update_mat(y,x) = current_value;
         endif 
      endif

    end
  end
  mat_a = update_mat;

end

figure(1)
imshow(mat_a./center_value)
```